# Regex and Htaccess help

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm very bad with regex and have no idea how to go about this.

I need to put a regex into an htaccess file so that all urls in the following format:

http://www.website.com/dir/1234-123
(2 integers of any length seperated by a dash)

will be redirected to:

http://www.website.com/file.php?a=1234&b=123
(a = integer 1, b = integer 2)

Does anyone know how to go about doing? Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about what `dir` means, but here you go:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dir/([0-9]*)\-([0-9]*)$ file.php?a=$1&b=$2
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need mod-rewrite enabled and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dir/([0-9]*)\-([0-9]*)$ file.php\?a=$1&b=$2
```